# Experimental examples of how to realize the photon coherent state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, resource-recommendations, experimental-technique, coherent-states

As well known in the theory of quantum optics, the photon coherent state is defined by
$$\hat{a}|\alpha\rangle = \alpha|\alpha\rangle$$
where $\hat{a}$ is the annihilation operator. Explicitly this state can be written as
$$|\alpha\rangle = e^{-\frac{|\alpha|^2}{2}}
  \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}}|n\rangle}$$
where $|n\rangle$ is the photon number state in the Fock space. $\alpha$ is a complex parameter, namely, $\alpha=|\alpha|e^{i\phi}$.

Where can I find any papers or references that have described the detail of the experiment for realizing the above photon coherent state?

Comment: I am not sure if single photon coherence is the same as general coherence. It usually is just a matter of spatial filtering (one single $k$ vector) and temporal filtering (one single frequency $\omega$) and then your phase is well behaved and the electromagnetic field has coherence properties. The wikipedia article on coherence explains this

Comment: The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeezed_coherent_state) contains several references.